# Attach the UIButton to Component Via Script (C# Unity)

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject, ngui

[image]

I want to attach the UI to the MC_Streaming Option Script via Code .

[image]

What i wanted here is that this `live_onOff` will go to the Livestream(MC_Streaming Option) without dragging it . And i don't know where to start.

PS: The MC_Streaming Option script is being attached only when the program run

```
MC_StreamingOption mcStreamingOption = gameObject.AddComponent<MC_StreamingOption>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the MC_StreamingOption doesn't exist at edit time, you can assign the button to another script to hold onto the button on its behalf until it's been spawned and is ready to accept it.

```
// 1) Member variable you can use to store a reference to the button in the Inspector.
public UIButton livestreamButton;

...

// 2) later, when you spawn the StreamingOption:
var mcStreamingOption = gameObject.AddComponent<MC_StreamingOption>();

// ...you assign the button you had set aside for it.
mcStreamingOption.livestream = livestreamButton;
```

Comment: i forgot mcStreamingOption.livestream = livestreamButton . Wow.... I'm so very idiot

Comment: Sir i have 1 more question